# What is the link between proj4js and proj

Tags: proj, proj4js

## Question

I am simply wondering, what is the relationship between the web oriented [proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) and the [PROJ](https://proj.org/) C++ well known library (on which for example [GDAL/OGR](https://gdal.org/) relies)?

Is there any link between these two libraries?

It's written on the [proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) web page that it is:

> Originally a port of PROJ.4 and GCTCP C it is a part of the MetaCRS group of projects.

But what is the current situation?
How could I check what version of [PROJ](https://proj.org/) does [proj4js](http://proj4js.org/) rely on?

### Sources repositories of each of these projets:

https://github.com/proj4js/proj4js
https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one "proj4js" is an adaptation from the second but not a port (same API in a different programming language)

The second PROJ (C++) is used directly or by program like PostGIS or GDAL to manage projections

Both take as an input mostly the same definitions for projection. You can confirm it with "Export" section from website epsg.io (an example https://epsg.io/2154)

If you want a literal JavaScript port of PROJ for JavaScript, you should look at https://github.com/mbloch/mapshaper-proj instead. It can be useful to get latest projections like "eqearth" or other not supported in proj4js (see https://proj.org/operations/projections/index.html for a list).

Comment: What if I need PROJ 6.x.x, for example for direct transforms or to compute cartesian geodetic coordiantes using proj4js? Is there any port of PROJ 6.x.x to a sister JS lib?

Comment: Not really sure. Not aware of a proj 6.x.x port inJS. Only clue could be about using C++ To Web Assembly to support it or creating your own back-end webservice and call it.